# How to avoid filesort when using left join and order by

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by, filesort

I have 3 tables: accounts, contacts and accounts_contacts (a mapping table).
I have abour1 million records in each of the tables. This query is using filesort and takes more than a minute to run:

```
explain SELECT contacts.salutation salutation, contacts.first_name first_name, contacts.last_name last_name, contacts.title title, jt0_accounts.id account_id, jt0_accounts.name account_name

FROM contacts

LEFT JOIN accounts_contacts jt1_accounts_contacts ON (contacts.id = jt1_accounts_contacts.contact_id AND jt1_accounts_contacts.deleted = 0)

LEFT JOIN accounts jt0_accounts ON (jt0_accounts.id = jt1_accounts_contacts.account_id AND jt0_accounts.deleted = 0)

ORDER BY jt0_accounts.name DESC;
```

This is the explain output:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1    SIMPLE contacts    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    195634  Using temporary; Using filesort
1    SIMPLE jt1_accounts_contacts   ref idx_contid_del_accid    idx_contid_del_accid    113 sugar7.contacts.id,const    1   
1   SIMPLE  jt0_accounts    eq_ref  PRIMARY,idx_accounts_id_del,idx_accounts_date_entered,idx_accnt_assigned_del    PRIMARY 108 sugar7.jt1_accounts_contacts.account_id 1
```

As you can see, contacts table is using filesort on contacts table.

I've tried getting rid of the filesort by adding a "WHERE jt0_accounts.name <> ''" before "ORDER BY" so it becomes:

```
explain SELECT contacts.salutation salutation, contacts.first_name first_name, contacts.last_name last_name, contacts.title title, jt0_accounts.id account_id, jt0_accounts.name account_name

FROM contacts

LEFT JOIN accounts_contacts jt1_accounts_contacts ON (contacts.id = jt1_accounts_contacts.contact_id AND jt1_accounts_contacts.deleted = 0)

LEFT JOIN accounts jt0_accounts ON (jt0_accounts.id = jt1_accounts_contacts.account_id AND jt0_accounts.deleted = 0)

WHERE jt0_accounts.name <> ''
ORDER BY jt0_accounts.name DESC;
```

It does get rid of the filesort on contacts table, but it's now using filesort on the mapping table:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  jt1_accounts_contacts   ALL idx_account_contact,idx_contid_del_accid    NULL    NULL    NULL    34994   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  jt0_accounts    eq_ref  PRIMARY,idx_accounts_id_del,idx_accounts_date_entered,idx_accnt_name_del,idx_accnt_assigned_del PRIMARY 108 sugar7.jt1_accounts_contacts.account_id 1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  contacts    eq_ref  PRIMARY,idx_contacts_id_del,idx_contacts_date_entered   PRIMARY 108 sugar7.jt1_accounts_contacts.contact_id 1   Using where
```

The idx_account_contact index consists of account_id and contacts_id. I've tried adding them to the WHERE clause but it does not seem to make any difference.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably not much that you can do about your particularly query.  But, if you change the query to use `inner join`, you might have a chance:

```
SELECT c.salutation, c.first_name, c.last_name, c.title,
       a.id as account_id, a.name as account_name
FROM accounts a JOIN
     accounts_contacts ac
     ON a.id = ac.account_id AND a.deleted = 0
     contacts c JOIN
     ON c.id = ac.contact_id AND ac.deleted = 0     
ORDER BY a.name DESC;
```

Then, try the following indexes:  `accounts(name, deleted, id)`, `accounts_contacts(account_id, contact_id)`, and `concats(contact_id, deleted)`.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, I don't think using inner join works for me. Because I want to show all records from contacts table, even if it has no associated accounts.

Comment: The performance of inner join is fine. I can replace "LEFT" with "INNER" in my original query and got the results in no time. But the results won't be what I expect.